# Finding smallest set of points satisfying given 1st and 2nd moment constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $n \times n$ positive semi-definite matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $n \times 1$ vector $\boldsymbol{b}$. The goal is to find a set of $K$ vectors $\boldsymbol{x}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{x}_K$ (each being $n \times 1$), with smallest possible value for $K$, such that these vectors satisfy moment constraints:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^K \boldsymbol{x}_k = \boldsymbol{b} \quad,\quad \sum_{k=1}^K \boldsymbol{x}_k \boldsymbol{x}_k^T = \boldsymbol{A} \,.
\end{equation}
Any thoughts on how to obtain $\boldsymbol{x}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{x}_K$?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the matrices and the vectors real?

Comment: They are all real.

Comment: Any positive semi-definite matrix can be written as $A = \sum_k \lambda_k x_k x_k^T = \sum_k y_k y_k^T $ where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues, $x_k$ the corresponding eigenvectors, and $y_k = \sqrt(\lambda_k) x_k$. So the space of solutions is a subset of the column space of $A$.

Comment: @Leo Are you suggesting that smallest K can never be bigger than n? That would be true if we only had the 2nd moment constraint, but together with 1st moment constraint, I think it is possible (depending on A and vb to have a situation where K>n. Please correct me if I misunderstood you.